# Codeigniter-passing value from controller to model

Tags: codeigniter

My English is not good so sorry for any mistake. I'm new to Codeigniter, I am trying to search record by using this code, this is my controller code:

```
public function search() {
    if(isset($_POST['search']))
    {
        $s = $_POST['search'];
        $this->db->select('u_id,name,email,phone');
        $this->db->from('user');
        $this->db->where('name =' ,"{$s}" );
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $res = $query->result();

        $data['user'] = null ;
        if($res)
        {
            $data['user'] = $res ;              
        }

        $this->load->view('filter' , $data);              
    }
}
```

It is working fine but I want to write this code in separate Model.

```
$this->db->select('u_id,name,email,phone');
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->where('name =' ,"{$s}" );
$query = $this->db->get();
$res = $query->result();
```

But i don't know how to pass this variable value `$s = $_POST['search'];` to my model. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the following

```
//in your application/models Folder put a File called UserSearch_Model.php

class UserSearch_Model extends CI_Model
{
    public function search($strSearch)
    {
        $query = $this->db
            ->select('u_id,name,email,phone')
            ->from('user')
            ->where('name' ,$s)
            ->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
}


//and in your controller

public function search() 
{
    $strSearch = $this->input->post('search');
    if (!empty($strSearch))
    {
        $data = [];
        $this->load->model("UserSearch_Model");
        $data['user'] = $this->UserSearch_Model->search($strSearch);

        if (is_array($data['user']) && count($data['user']) > 0)
        {
            $this->load->view('filter' , $data);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem :

```
public function search() {
    $search_value = $this->input->post('search'));
    $this->db->select('u_id,name,email,phone');
    $this->db->from('user');
    if (isset($search_value) && !empty($search_value)) {
        $this->db->where('name',$search_value);
        // OR
        $this->db->like('name', $search_value);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $res = $query->result();
    $data['user'] = null;
    if ($res) {
        $data['user'] = $res;
    }
    $this->load->view('filter', $data);
}
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but i want to make model for selecting record from db you just modified the code of controller which don't help in my case because my code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

#### Controller

```
public function search() {
    $search = $this->input->post('search');
    $this->load->model('your_model'); //<-- You can load the model into "__construct"

    $search_result = $this->your_model->your_search_function($search); //<-- This is how you can pass a variable to the model from controller

    $this->load->view('your_view',['search_result'=>$search_result]); //<-- This is how you can load the data to the view. Hear your search result array is loaded on your view

}
```

#### Model

```
public function your_search_function($search) {

//You will receive this search variable ^^ here in your model

    $this->db->select('u_id,name,email,phone');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->where('name',$search);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();

    if(isset($result) && !empty($result))
    {
        return $result;
    } else 
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```